# Get problem with Binlog_Do_DB in Master configuration

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.1

I have followed all the rules for replication. The steps are
I have changed the my.cnf file. My db name is new_db.

```
server-id   = 1
log_bin = D:/xampp/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = new_db
```

Grant the replication for slave

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
USE new_db;
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

After that the result is

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000003 |      481 |              |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Binlog_Do_DB column is empty. new_db should be there.

I don't understand what I missed. Please help to solve the problem.

Comment: In Windows you would need to modify the my.ini file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you would need to modify the my.ini file and not the my.cnf file

[Locate you my.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/mysql-my-ini-location)

If MySQL is being run as a service

1. Enter "services.msc" on the Start menu search box.
2. Find MySQL service under Name column, for example, MySQL56.
3. Right click on MySQL service, and select Properties menu.
4. Look for "Path To Executable" under General tab, and there is your .ini file, for instance, "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MYSQL56

Otherwise the my.ini file is probably in a sub-directory of D:\xampp\mysql\

Once you've added in the binlog_do_db parameter, be sure to restart the MySQL service.

**Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA**

You can restart mysql from `services.msc` window by right clicking and choosing or you can login from DOS CommandLine as Administrator as run

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

Also, make sure your settings are under the `[mysqld]` group header in `my.ini`

Comment: I tried it but its still the same issue. I am using xampp here.

Comment: Hello @Moumita, it seems doubtful that you are modifying the correct my.ini file. Are you absolutely sure you are updating the right one?

Comment: One more thing I add in file.
log-bin="D:/xampp/mysql/data/binlog/bin-log".